# I'm trying to normalize the documents column within the dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

```
[{
    'processingTechniques': ['Hot rolling'],
    'summary': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'applications': ['CONCRETE REINFORCEMENT', 'METAL DOWNSTREAM INDUSTRIALS', 'CUT AND BEND', 'EPOXY COATING '],
    'regions': ['MEA'],
    'description': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'industrySegments': None,
    'grade_id': '89a63243-74c7-e611-8197-06b69393ae39',
    'name': '40',
    'documents': [{
        'documentType': 'TDS',
        'title': 'Rebar in Coil_40_Global_Technical_Data_Sheet',
        'url': '/en/products/documents/rebar-in-coil_40_global_technical_data_sheet/en',
        'language': 'English',
        'region': 'Global',
        'revision': '20210812',
        'id': '2bc4102f-8df7-e611-819b-06b69393ae39'
    }]
}, {
    'processingTechniques': ['Hot rolling'],
    'summary': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'applications': ['CONCRETE REINFORCEMENT', 'METAL DOWNSTREAM INDUSTRIALS', 'CUT AND BEND', 'EPOXY COATING '],
    'regions': ['MEA'],
    'description': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'industrySegments': None,
    'grade_id': 'dddd0468-79c7-e611-8197-06b69393ae39',
    'name': '460B',
    'documents': [{
        'documentType': 'TDS',
        'title': 'Rebar in Coil_460B_MEA_Technical_Data_Sheet',
        'url': '/en/products/documents/rebar-in-coil_460b_mea_technical_data_sheet/en',
        'language': 'English',
        'region': 'MEA',
        'revision': '20210812',
        'id': '0e63bc98-c343-e811-80fd-005056857ef3'
    }]
}, {
    'processingTechniques': ['Hot rolling'],
    'summary': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'applications': ['CONCRETE REINFORCEMENT', 'METAL DOWNSTREAM INDUSTRIALS', 'CUT AND BEND', 'EPOXY COATING '],
    'regions': ['MEA'],
    'description': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'industrySegments': None,
    'grade_id': 'cd695035-76c7-e611-8197-06b69393ae39',
    'name': '60',
    'documents': [{
        'documentType': 'TDS',
        'title': 'Rebar in Coil_60_MEA_Technical_Data_Sheet',
        'url': '/en/products/documents/rebar-in-coil_60_mea_technical_data_sheet/en',
        'language': 'English',
        'region': 'MEA',
        'revision': '20210812',
        'id': '733946d8-c343-e811-80fd-005056857ef3'
    }]
}, {
    'processingTechniques': ['Hot rolling'],
    'summary': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'applications': ['CONCRETE REINFORCEMENT', 'METAL DOWNSTREAM INDUSTRIALS', 'CUT AND BEND', 'EPOXY COATING '],
    'regions': ['MEA'],
    'description': 'Metals Long Products Rebar in Coil',
    'industrySegments': None,
    'grade_id': 'c99a8cc9-79c7-e611-8197-06b69393ae39',
    'name': 'B500B',
    'documents': [{
        'documentType': 'TDS',
        'title': 'Rebar in Coil_B500B_MEA_Technical_Data_Sheet',
        'url': '/en/products/documents/rebar-in-coil_b500b_mea_technical_data_sheet/en',
        'language': 'English',
        'region': 'MEA',
        'revision': '20210812',
        'id': 'bc25a637-c443-e811-80fd-005056857ef3'
    }]
}]
```

The code written to convert this json to dataframe after normalizing the document is this

```
gr2 = pd.json_normalize(result, ['documents'], meta = ['regions', 'name', 'description', 'grade_id', 'processingTechniques','summary', 'applications'])
gr2['product_id'] = prod_id
gr2.head()
```

**result** is the json file attached above.
After running the above code, I'm getting this error

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ? I just want documents to get normalised along with the other columns.

Comment: One of the column might be having 16 row values with a shape `(16, )` and the other might be having only 4 row values, that's what the error says. Check the whether all the columns have equal number of values.

Comment: how should the final df look like?

Comment: I want dataframe with these columns : 

['documentType',  'title', 'url', 'language', 'region', 'revision', 'id', 'regions','name','description', 'grade_id', 'processingTechniques', 'summary', 'applications', 'product_id']